# How to set FormCalc round to nearest quarter hour?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, livecycle, adobe-reader

I have this time sheet that has four "In" and four "Out" columns,and calculates hours worked in a two week pay period. There is a column on the right that calculates the hours worked for the day (see script below). I need it to round to the nearest quarter hour i.e.,

If an employee arrives or leaves between:

```
":00" to ":07" minutes after the hour, calculate from the top of the hour
":08" to ":22" minutes after the hour, calculate from quarter after the hour
":23" to ":37" minutes after the hour, calculate from the half hour
":38" to ":52" minutes after the hour, calculate from three quarters past the hour
":53" to ":60" minutes after the hour, calculate from the top of the hour
```

Examples:

```
An employee records that they arrived at 8:07 a.m. Calculate from 8:00
An employee records that they arrived at 8:08 a.m. Calculate from 8:15
An employee records that they arrived at 8:22 a.m. Calculate from 8:30
An employee records that they arrived at 8:37 a.m. Calculate from 8:45
An employee records that they arrived at 8:53 a.m. Calculate from 9:00
```

Script in "Hours Worked" column

```
// compute block 0
var StartInterval = 0
if(HasValue(OUTA1[0]) and HasValue(INA1[0])) then
StartInterval = Time2Num(OUTA1[0].formattedValue, "HH:MM") - Time2Num(INA1[0].formattedValue, "HH:MM")
endif

// compute block 1
var LunchInterval = 0
if(HasValue(OUTA1[1]) and HasValue(INA1[1])) then
LunchInterval = Time2Num(OUTA1[1].formattedValue, "HH:MM") - Time2Num(INA1[1].formattedValue, "HH:MM")
endif

// compute block 2
var EndInterval = 0
if(HasValue(OUTA1[2]) and HasValue(INA1[2])) then
EndInterval = Time2Num(OUTA1[2].formattedValue, "HH:MM") - Time2Num(INA1[2].formattedValue, "HH:MM")
endif

// compute total time in hours from the millisecond value
Round(Sum(StartInterval, LunchInterval, EndInterval) / 3600000,2)
```

Comment: And your question would be ... what?

Comment: How do I get it to round to the nearest quarter hour? I know how to do it in excel using =(ROUND(B2*96, 0)/96)-(ROUND(A2*96, 0)/96). But I'm at a loss with FormCalc. Any idea?